# Users getting "Denied access" to 10.14.6 server upon being kicked out

Tags: mojave, server.app, smb, file-sharing

I recently set up a new macOS 10.14.6 server. It is a Mac Pro Late 2013 set up with about 20 users connected to a a Enstore RAID via an external SAS Card running Thunderbolt 2 external PCIe card.

I have issues with users being kicked off then when trying to reconnect they are being denied access. As if something has timed out or they have tried to connect too many times. (Server) performance mode is on.

There is no Active Directory/Open Directory active in the network and all the users are local sharing accounts.

I have tried both IP address and FQDN.
Those that do connect with SMB find that files and folders are missing. Is there a fix for this?

---

Update:

I came in this morning and SMB connections are refusing logins. I get this error when I try to log in.

> opendirectoryd[some_pid]: [default] Failed to open file <⁠private⁠> [2: No such file or directory]

Users can connect via AFP though.

Comment: Did you try to connect with server IP when the user tries to connect?

Comment: So No AD or OD all local sharing Users as per new mac Server workings. Tried with Both domain and IP address. Users connecting with smb

Comment: Please edit your question and add all details there...(even if **no** AD/OD is in use). Connection/error logs are still appreciated - before adding them you should sanitize them though and replace host names/user names/IDs/tokens etc. But don't oversanitize them: server-1st-floor.google.es shouldn't become xxx.yyy.zzz but server.sld.tld...

Comment: Updated with relevant issue